# Bluetooth not working on Linux Ubutu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, bluez

I use Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBY and Bluetooth not work on it.
I tried everything.

```
 dmesg | grep -i blue

[    5.461174] usb 2-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   37.717441] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   37.717482] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   37.717489] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   37.717493] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   37.717505] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   70.111614] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834591.399:98): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=1830 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[   70.200878] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834591.491:99): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1814 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   70.247306] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834591.535:100): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1830 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   70.562212] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834591.851:101): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2140 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   70.567063] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834591.855:102): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=2138 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[   70.567905] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834591.855:103): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2138 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   70.818731] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834592.107:104): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2219 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   70.826299] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834592.115:105): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=2217 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[   70.826987] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834592.115:106): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2217 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   71.327463] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834592.615:110): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=2359 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[   71.328408] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834592.619:111): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2359 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   71.390956] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834592.679:112): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2371 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   71.669183] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834592.959:114): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=2467 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[   71.671398] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834592.959:115): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2467 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   71.684614] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834592.975:116): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2466 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  278.307006] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834799.132:124): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.btmon" pid=11885 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  278.312642] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834799.140:125): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.hcidump" pid=11886 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  278.412302] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834799.240:126): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.bluez" pid=11888 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  278.414419] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834799.240:127): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.bluetoothctl" pid=11889 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  278.414721] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834799.240:128): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=11890 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  278.416738] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834799.244:129): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.btattach" pid=11891 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  278.418158] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834799.244:130): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.btmgmt" pid=11892 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  278.419968] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834799.248:131): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.hciattach" pid=11893 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  278.421610] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834799.248:132): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.hciconfig" pid=11894 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  278.421754] audit: type=1400 audit(1595834799.248:133): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.hcitool" pid=11895 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1027.216275] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 1027.216278] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 1027.216287] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 1027.339253] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 1027.339267] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 1027.339281] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

    rfkill list all

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no\

systemctl status bluetooth.service
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-07-27 09:39:07 CEST; 21min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 25542 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─25542 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

јул 27 09:39:07 Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBY systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth se
јул 27 09:39:07 Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBY bluetoothd[25542]: Bluetooth daem
јул 27 09:39:07 Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBY systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth ser
јул 27 09:39:07 Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBY bluetoothd[25542]: Starting SDP s
јул 27 09:39:07 Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBY bluetoothd[25542]: Bluetooth mana
lines 1-15/15 (END)...skipping...
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-07-27 09:39:07 CEST; 21min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 25542 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─25542 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

When I turn on Bluetooth, none of device doesn't appear, just loading and search.